# pointing to a data table in SPOTFIRE

Tags: spotfire

Currently I am pointing all my analysis to TABLE1. But i want to point out the same analysis to TABLE2 instead of TABLE1 in SPOTFIRE.

TABLE1 and TABLE2 have information links created for each in SPOTFIRE.

How can i point my analysis to TABLE2 instead of TABLE1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of transformations you did on your data, you can replace data table as long as you can match the columns. For example, if columns names are different, then you could match col1 = column1. It should be straight forward if your T2 has same column names. No need to recreate calculated columns. If T2 has more columns than T1, you can add them. Otherwise (if T1 has more columns than T2) they will no longer be available.